# Path does not scale proportionally and causes overflow

Tags: adobe-illustrator, path, scale

I'm using Illustrator CC and I am new to it, so I would like to hear your professional advice on how to solve a problem with scaling a path in Illustrator.

I've used the Pen Tool to create a path in the illustration. It looks good when original dimensions of illustration have being displayed:

[image: original dimensions of illustration]

When I try to make the illustration smaller, the path does not scale, and it also causes some overflow issues:

[image: scaled illustration]

I've tried to turn on "Scale strokes and effects" but it does not resolve the problem.

Any ideas how to prevent it? Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That doesn't make sense, unless you aren't scaling everything uniformly that should work. Are the white "reflections" above or below the blue "frames". Try reordering the elements?

Answer (score 1):

Alin might be right, but if you want to make 100% sure, make a copy of the document, select all and covert paths to outlines. This converts every line to a shape and then everything should scale proportionally.

Comment: It didn't make sense to me  why that would happen so I copied the big image and scaled it down myself and it does give that impression. It's the combination of big vs. small rectangle and having only one "glow" instead of two [not having the second one to compare with] + the choice of colors might have a role in this.

Comment: Lucian is right. I think the only problem is the stroke of your window line. It does not scale properly when your only dragging it down or up. As mentioned Lucian is right to expand or to make it all to outlines.

Answer (score 0):

It DOES scale, test it yourself, what you see is just an **optical illusion** (image below, try it yourself).

> After scaling down, zoom in till it becomes bigger and you will see
>   that sensation goes away or zoom out from the original shape and you
>   will have the same sensation.

[image]